# Remove multiple Firebase listeners created inside viewHolder

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, listener

How do I remove multiple listeners created for each view item?

```
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(final MessageViewHolder viewHolder, final Friends msg, int position) {


                online = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("online").child(msg.friend_id);
                    userListener = online.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            Online online = dataSnapshot.getValue(Online.class);
                            if(online != null){
                                if (viewHolder.getDiff(online.timestamp) < 1){
                                    viewHolder.donline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                    System.out.println("Is online");
                                } else {
                                    viewHolder.donline.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                            }

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }

                    });


            }

        };
```

Upon reopening app it will create a new listener for each item in the viewHolder. How do I deatach them all inside onDestroy?

Comment: Try this:-  online.removeEventListener(userListener)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To deatach multiple `listeners` you can use the following method:

```
public static void removeValueEventListener(HashMap<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> hashMap) {
    for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> entry : hashMap.entrySet()) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = entry.getKey();
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = entry.getValue();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }
}
```

And don't forget to use this method according to your life-cycle of your acitivty:

```
removeValueEventListener(hashMap);
```

Comment: It might work, but the problem is that upon creating the view, listeners are not inserted in the hashmap. Do multiple listeners are created as a hashmap automatically or not?

Comment: Yes, you need to add those listeners to a `Map`. And yes, if you use the method from above using the `Map`, in `onDestroy` all listener are automatically stoped.

Comment: Yes, I added every single listener to a map and onStop I delete them all as onDestroy not always fires up for some reson, thanks for pointing to the right direction